# "prepareRenderer" doesn't work when I put data from xml into my customJTable

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtable, windowsbuilder

i'm working on a personal project with Java and Swing under Eclipse.

I've a custom JTable to render cells.

```
public class CustomJTable extends JTable{

@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
{
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

    // change background of rows if [row,13] is even
    c.setBackground(getBackground());
    if( (int)getModel().getValueAt(row, 13) %2 == 0)
        c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    // change font, border e background of cells if a string field is equal to some predeterminated value
    Font myFont = new Font(TOOL_TIP_TEXT_KEY, Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 12);
    c.setForeground(getForeground());

    if (getModel().getValueAt(row, column)=="VALUE"){
        ((JComponent) c).setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.RED)); //needs cast for using setBorder
        c.setFont(myFont);
        c.setForeground(Color.RED);
        c.setBackground(new Color(255, 230, 230));
    }

    //set disabled cells appearance
    if (getModel().getValueAt(row, column)=="DISABLED"){
        ((JComponent) c).setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.GRAY));
        c.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }

    return c;
}
```

My CustomJTable take values from a custom TableModel (extends AbstractTableModel) that contains a vector of class with overrided methods.

If I add an element in the vector with something like this `myModel.getVector().add(element)` I have no problem. 
After I type `myTable.updateUI()`, Row is automatically added to CustomJtable and it's right and rendered as well. Everything is perfect!!!

The problem occure when I try to add rows from an external .XML that I saved before.
Data that I added to my JTable are right, YELLOW rows background changed as well, but cells are not rendered (not cells border, not font change, not RED cells background).

I tried everything. `validate()`, `repaint()`, `fireTableCellChanged()`...
I cannot find error. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getModel().getValueAt(row, column)=="VALUE"` >> that's more than likely an error already. If you want to compare strings, you need to use `Object.equals` to compare those. Like this: `"VALUE".equals(getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString())`. You make the same mistake a bit further comparing to the string `"DISABLED"`.

The second mistake is that you are using view indexes to index in the model. The `row` and `column` parameters passed in the `JTable.prepareRenderer` method are view indexes. You can't use those to index the model as you are doing in `getModel().getValueAt(row, column)`. You need to translate those indexes using [`JTable.convertRowIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-) and [`JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel-int-) before calling `getModel().getValueAt()`. You can read more about this in the introductory description in the [JTable documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).

Alternatively, use [`JTable.getValueAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt-int-int-) instead. Here you can use the view indexes passed to `JTable.prepareRenderer`.

Comment: OMG, thanks a lot.
I returned to Java from a lot of years and I didn't the difference between view indexes and model indexes. That was the problem!